# Kubernetes fails to create loadbalancer on azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

We have created the kubernetes cluster on the azure VM, with Kube master and two nodes. We have deployed application and created the service with "NodePort" which works well. But when we try to use the type: LoadBalancer then it create service but the external IP goes pending state. Currently we unable create service type load balance and due this "ingress" nginx controller also going to same state. So we are not sure how do we setup load balancing in this case.

We have tried creating Load Balancer in Azure and trying to use that ip like shown below in service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jira-service
  labels:
    app: jira-software
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    app: jira-software
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ports:
  - name: jira-http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: jira-http
```

similarly we have one more application running on this kube cluster and we want to access application based on the context path.
if we invoke jira it should call backend server jira `http://dns-name/jira`
if we invoke some other app like bitbucket `http://dns-name/bitbukcet`

Comment: you have a bunch of completely non related questions here mixed in 1. what do the error logs show when you try to create the load balancer? `kubectl get events`?

Comment: What type of network do you use? Basic or Advance? When you use the special IP for your load balancer, you should make sure the IP is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you used type LoadBalancer in Virtual Machine, which will not work - type LoadBalancer works only in managed Kubernetes services like GKE, AKS etc.

You can find more information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).